# Declare method type in angular

Tags: javascript, angular

In Angular, if you don't declare a function as `private`, it is automatically `public`.

Is it necessary to add the method type?

```
public getAllUsers() { ... }

getAllUsers() { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with Angular but is is all about TypeScript. Methods that are not declared as private or protected are automatically public. So declaring a method as public is entirely optional.

So declaring two methods

```
public getAllUsers() {
}
```

or

```
getAllUsers(){
}
```

is completely equivalent.